# Is it OK to include external files in cache-manifest?

Tags: jquery, html, caching, offline, offline-browsing

I'm building an offline web application and want to use cache-manifest. Currently my cache-manifest looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Change the version number below each time we update a resource.
# Rev 1
index.html
photo.html
js/photo.js
css/photo.css
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;region=GB
```

Is there any reason **not** to include external, CDN-hosted jQuery, jQuery Mobile and Google Maps files in the cache-manifest?

I can't think of one, but I thought I would ask those wiser than myself :)

Comment: I don't think the answer is correct.
Please see [this other question on SO][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795268/can-i-use-html5-cache-manifest-to-store-third-party-js

Comment: Please recheck answers; I suspect the accepted answer is incorrect and it caused a lot of confusion. I have provided a different answer with sources.

Comment: Please recheck the valid answer

Answer (score -7, accepted):

You cant. Cache Manifest will only work for files from same domain. You would need to proxy from your domain if you want to white-list for cross-domain resources.

Comment: This answer is **INCORRECT** at least for images, but probably also for scripts (please see my answer for sources). Please check again and either provide a source or delete/correct the answer, since this comes up in Google searches and is very confusing.

Comment: Lol folks this was answered in 2011 (almost 3 years ago!) geesus. Original poster can mark it as incorrect and update with the right answer.

Answer (score 19):

Yes. Actually, you **must** include external images in your manifest, or some browsers will not load them at all even if a network connection is available! (Unless you provide a NETWORK section, which may cause the images to be fetched every time, bypassing the regular browser cache.)

The images **will** be cached (at least by Firefox, didn't test Chrome).

The [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#manifests) explicitly says:

> Offline application cache manifests can use absolute paths or even absolute URLs

http://manifest-validator.com/ also reports a manifest with external URLs as OK.

I am not 100% sure this also applies to scripts, but a quick test with Firefox looked like the script is cached as expected.

Answer (score 2):

MobileSafari has a rule that under SSL, all paths in the applicationCache must conform to same-origin policy. The applicationCache will cache successfully with foreign-origin paths, but you will not see those resources listed in the Web Inspector->Storage->ApplicationCache table, and they will not be available when offline.

This behavior isn't described in Apple's documentation but is still apparent in iOS 10.2: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/OfflineApplicationCache/OfflineApplicationCache.html

Comment: [W3 specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/offline.html#writing-cache-manifests): If the manifest is https, all URLs must have the same origin as the manifest