# Can I use html5 cache manifest to store third party js?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache, cache-manifest

I want to use third party js in my html5 cache manifest.
I don't know can I do it or not , if its possible then how?
Can I specify full third party js url in manifest file?
I have seen examples where in manifest they have specified http url for images , So why can't we do same for js & css?
If we can't implement it , is there any other option? I know that we can store third party js in local storage.
Example is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [html5doctors](http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/), you can set external urls in the cache manifest. Here is an example:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# This is the cache part where you specify files to cache
CACHE
/some/file.js
/some/other/file.css

http://some.external.url/file.js
```

I suggest you read the link to html5doctors if you want more information (cache, fallback, etc).

Comment: I have product which will run on other's site.I want to reduce loading time , also person can use it even he is offline.

Comment: I have seen examples where in manifest they have specified http url for images , So why can't we do same for js & css?

Comment: can you please tell me if I can use it while I am online?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing problems, I had an issue with trying load scripts from https. Converting them to http did the trick.